# intersection between two files linux

Tags: linux, unix, centos

I need to compare the difference between two files in lunix exactly I need the intersection for exmple I have in the firts file test.txt this lines

aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd

and in the seconde file test2.txt this lines

eeee
ffff
aaaa
gggg
dddd

I need the result as this

aaaa
dddd

I use this commande

```
comm -23 <(sort -i  /var/test.txt) <(sort -i  /var/test2.txt) > g.txt
```

and this is the result

bbbb
cccc

I need the intersection between test and test1 any help

grep take alof of memeory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear whether you are attempting to pick off certain numeric columns (e.. `2, 3, etc..)` or if you are attempting to find common words in a line in two separate files (I take the latter to be your goal, let me know if I'm wrong).

In that case, you cannot suppress any column from either file because you don't know which column the common words will reside in after `sort`. One column agnostic way to fine and output the common words in sort-order is to simply `sort` one file, take your pick, and then loop over the sorted words calling `grep -q` to test whether a word is present in the second file, and if so output it (you can control line format as you desire)

One, not especially pretty way to accomplish this is:

```
for i in $(printf "%s\n" | sort -i test1.txt)  ## loop over sorted test1.txt
do 
    grep -q "$i" test2.txt && echo -n "$i "    ## grep if value in test2.txt
done
echo ""
```

You can wrap it in a subshell (e.g. `(....)` and just copy and pasted it into your terminal (in the directory with the files `test1.txt` and `test2.txt`) to see if this meets your needs, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ (
>     for i in $(printf "%s\n" | sort -i test1.txt)
>     do
>         grep -q "$i" test2.txt && echo -n "$i "
>     done
>     echo ""
> )
aaaa dddd
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: yes wok but what about the performance with a big large files  ??

Comment: Well, I don't particularly like that it will call `grep` once for each term in `test1.txt`, but there isn't a way around that. An `awk` field comparison is still a call to `awk` for each of the sorted terms, so that is mostly a wash. If there were a significant difference in the sizes of `test1.txt` and `test2.txt`, you would want to sort and iterate over the smaller one to limit the number of calls in the loop. Other than that, you are somewhat limited to what is available to your shell.

Comment: thnaks I slove the problem wiht writting code java to compare very fast for the large files thanks very mucth for your reponse

Answer (score 1):

`man comm`:

```
 EXAMPLES
        comm -12 file1 file2
               Print only lines present in both file1 and file2.
```

So:

```
$ comm -12 <(sort -i  test.txt) <(sort -i  test2.txt)
aaaa
dddd
```